# Kiosk-Arcade Game

Tags: google-chrome, kiosk, google-chrome-os, kiosk-mode, chromebook

I am attempting to build an kiosk app for chromebooks to allow them to play a single game offline effectively making it an arcade game. It looks like the code for most kiosk apps makes them access a certain webpage but not another app on the chromebook like I want. The chrome app builder simply pulls up a blank page when I try to direct it to an extension instead of a webpage and so do the app I try to program myself. I am a programming novice an would appreciate any wisdom that you could share.

Comment: To summarize, you're trying to build a kiosk app that runs an existing chrome extension inside the kiosk app?  Do you have access to the extension's source code?